# Error with distance calculation is objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, mongodb, distance

I am trying to get the distance between Houston Tx and San Francisco (Apple headquarters) and am getting some crazy results that are not making sense.

The distance in that I get between Houston TX and San Francisco comes out to be :
217.52603273007 using the distance property between two lat/lon coordinates

I then use the following code to try to get the distance in miles by multiplying with 3959

```
 NSNumber * distanceMiles = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[classified valueForKeyPath:@"distance"]intValue] * 3959];

    cell.distance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ miles", distanceMiles];
```

I am getting 859103 which makes no sense whatsoever!!!

What am I doing wrong?

The distance (by air) between San Francisco, CA and Houston, TX is approximately 1651 miles (2658 km).

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the distance from, but radians are not a measure of distance. Radians measure an angle and range from 0 to 2π

Comment: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing     I have started to hate Mongo for its lack of adequate documentation.

Comment: I just followed documentation and got 1615.7 miles - seems reasonable to me.

Comment: how? Please explain. In my mongo query, my command is:  ->field('coordinates')->geoNear((float)$longitude, (float)$latitude);

Comment: maybe your longtitude, latitude coordinates are wrong.  I used 95.3631, 29.7631 for Houston and 122.0311, 37.3231 for Apple (Cupertino, which is where Apple HQ is located).  I got "dis" : 0.4081109209840864, which I multiplied by 3959 to get 1615.

Comment: if you could add both the query you are using and the actual values you are using for the locations...  the error could be in the data, not the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which part of your input may be wrong but here is how I did it following the documentation you [linked](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

```
db.geo.insert({city:"Houston",coord:[95.3631, 29.7631]})
db.geo.ensureIndex({coord:'2d'})
db.runCommand({ geoNear : "geo", near : [122.0311, 37.3231], spherical : true, maxDistance : 1})
{
    "ns" : "so.geo",
    "near" : "1110001101101100111000000110111000010111001101100110",
    "results" : [
        {
            "dis" : 0.4081109209840864,
            "obj" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("506f9a035a6639f6e19a3dea"),
                "city" : "Houston",
                "coord" : [
                    95.3631,
                    29.7631
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
       ...
```

Comment: I am using Mongo ODM. I have added my query to the top. I am so close and thanks sooo much for posting this. Just not sure why and where it is messing up

Comment: you should add your query to your original question (or as a comment to the question or to the answer).  It would be very confusing to have it as part of the answer, since it's actually part of the question :)